# XAMPP PHP OPENSSL openssl_pkey_get_details() crashes webpage

Tags: php, apache, openssl, xampp

I currently have OpenSSL configured in XAMPP on Windows. Following [this](http://3stepsbeyond.co.uk/2010/12/openssl-and-php-tutorial-part-one/) tutorial, I tried to use the following code:

```
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 1024,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privateKey, 'private.key');
$a_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);
file_put_contents('public.key', $a_key['key']);
openssl_free_key($privateKey);
```

When I open the page I get a "Webpage Not Available" error. I have managed to pinpoint the problem to `openssl_pkey_get_details()` because if I remove this the page successfully loads. Additionally, a *private.key* is generated without a problem in the first part of the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please look into error log files (Apache2 and PHP5) and tell us what fatal lies there.

Comment: Seems that Apache refuses to handle request because of mismatching certificates.

Comment: Would you happen to be able to point me in the direction of solving this? A Google search didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: I'd really like to help you, but this is something that requires checking your exact systems configurations, so please check if you can generate certificates once again, setup the SSL config so that entries correspond to valid and accessible paths, and also check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/414411/session-cache-is-not-configured-why

Comment: @kpsuperplane Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @user427969 Not yet sadly

Comment: @kpsuperplane Thanks for replying. I am having similar issue but cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported at [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55470&edit=3).

If you replace **libeay32.dll** and **ssleay32.dll** in **xampp/apache/bin** with the same files in **xampp/php/** then it works but you CANNOT use SSL.

I have tried this and it works. I am using OpenSSL library in PHP(5.4.7) on XAMPP(1.8.1). However, I had to disable SSL.